# What are shortcodes and why does Theme Forest provide them?

Tags: html, themes

I'm new to coding and I have already googled my question, But i'm not exactly sure if it's correct. I'd like to cross check with the community.

I bought a theme from Theme Forest and was given short codes for various things like buttons or hover effects.

Are these meant to be used for a wordpress theme? Can I use them in my html and css? I am hardcoding my site at the moment. Are these useful to me at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A shortcode is a WordPress-specific code that lets you do nifty things with very little effort. Shortcodes can embed files or create objects that would normally require lots of complicated, ugly code in just one line. Shortcode = shortcut.

Source: http://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/